# Creating a tree output with - and *

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm working on creating a "tree" output with -'s and *'s for a homework project. The bottom should mirror the top. I'm close, with the top completed, but my bottom "mirror" portion doesn't produce enough *'s. Here's what it's supposed to be:

```
-------*
------***
-----*****
----*******
---*********
--***********
-*************
***************
-*************
--***********
---*********
----*******
-----*****
------***
-------*
```

I've tried modifying the top for loop in reverse and editing the range values, changing the order of the nested for loops, and the order of the range values. My code below shows the closest I've come to the desired output, but I'm wondering if I'm on the wrong track or forgetting something minor.

```
for rowCount in range(1, 9):
    for dashCount in range(1, 9 - rowCount):
        print("-", end='')
    for starCount in range(1, 2* rowCount):
        print("*", end='')
    print()
for rowCount in range(0,7):
    for dashCount in range(1,2 + rowCount):
        print("-", end='')
    for starCount in range(0,7 - rowCount):
        print("*", end='')
    print()
```

expected:

```
-------*
------***
-----*****
----*******
---*********
--***********
-*************
***************
-*************
--***********
---*********
----*******
-----*****
------***
-------*
```

actual:

```
-------*
------***
-----*****
----*******
---*********
--***********
-*************
***************
-*******
--******
---*****
----****
-----***
------**
-------*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should double the number of stars of the bottom tree.

Change:

```
for starCount in range(0,7 - rowCount):
```

to:

```
for starCount in range(0, 13 - 2 * rowCount):
```